# Crash on swizzled_addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I'm using `DAKeyboardControl`. I got crash when i go back from controller

Here is code for go back from controller :

```
- (IBAction)onClickBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here is crash image :

[image]

here `self` is `UIViewControllerWrapperView` kind of class that get crash.

`<UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x79e8d220; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e8d3d0>>`

and yes i also remove it from `viewDidDisappear` .

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.view removeKeyboardControl];
}
```

What is problem here ?

```
**EDIT**
```

I added two viewController to one `HomeController` and hide show on button click of `HomeController`.

Now in create new object ob click of my viewController that need to reconnect my chatting room. so may be it's prob ? 
But how to resolve it ?

Comment: Possible a conflict in observer for keyboard or your view is not removed from parent and you are adding it again. check your ViewController's lifecyle method calling sequence to trace it down.

Answer (score 0):

As a doc says about `viewDidDisappear` method

> Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view
>   hierarchy.

Also in header `DAKeyboardControl` the comment for this method

> /** Remove the keyboard action handler  @note You MUST call this
>   method to remove the keyboard handler before the view goes out of
>   memory.  */

Try to change a bit your method to

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.view removeKeyboardControl];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

or use it in `viewWillDisappear` method

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.view removeKeyboardControl];
}
```